# CakePHP make url pretty

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I know `Pretty` is subjective however i wish to shorten down my urls.

right now an example of my URLS would look like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/cake/index.php/controller/action
```

is it possible to shorten this down, and if so how much?

Comment: Don't you use mod_rewrite?

Comment: @mark i do ? but what does that has to do with anything :D

Comment: Everything I am afraid. The url would look like `www.mydomain.com/controller/action`

Comment: @mark mod_rewrite is enabled do i need to add something to my bootstrap file or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In configs/routes.php, you can try something like

```
Router::connect('/Your-Customize-URL/*', array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'));
```

For more detail: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: is it possible to remove the cake/index.php/ from the url ? the above code will only change the controller and action